# Spring: use different beans in one controller

Tags: java, spring-mvc, controller, javabeans

I have following issue: we've been developing website using Spring tools 3.8.3 and one of the option is to allow users to reset their passwords. In order to do that they need to specify their email address and validate captcha. When these steps are completed data is sent to ResetPassword controller which does all necessary checks and work. Controller has following address:

```
website.com/path/resetPassword/
```

And has following structure where it extends abstract controller template to define the input and output beans:

```
@RequestMapping(path="website.com/path/resetPassword/",
                consumes = "application/JSON",
                produces = "application/JSON",
                method = "POST")
public class ResetPassController extends ControllerTemplate<ResetPassCaptchaBean, ResponseBean>{ 

// Autowired field declaration

// Couple of methods calling services
}
```

The bean also has only two fields - email and captcha accordingly. Captcha field **uses annotation** to check if either it's valid or not:

```
public class ResetPassCaptchaBean extends ResetPassBean {
    @CaptchaValid
    private String captcha;

    public void setCaptcha(String captcha) {
        this.captcha = captcha;
    }

    public String getCaptcha() {
        return captcha;
    }
}

public class ResetPassBean {

    private String email;

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email= email;
    }

    public String getCaptcha() {
        return email;
    }
}
```

Now we are adding mobile API and it's necessary to do the same procedure but without using captcha validation. Therefore we're simply using the bean without captcha field. Since captcha is validated using the annotation in the bean it's completely not used in the controller itself and therefore we'd like to have **the same** controller both for handling requests from web site and from mobile API.

I understand that it's possible to create two different controllers and move all the implementation to service layer (read other class) but then there still would be two identical classes with only one line difference

```
public class ResetPassController extends ControllerTemplate<ResetPassCaptchaBean, ResponseBean>{
    //Autowiring same stuff

    //Calling same methods
}
```

and

```
public class MobileResetPassController extends ControllerTemplate<ResetPassBean, ResponseBean>{
    //Autowiring stuff

    //Calling same methods
}
```

So the question is: leave it with two identical controllers or is there other solution?
Thanks!

Comment: Consider implementing a common interface both reset beans, and then changing your ResetPassCaptchaBean into a Decorator for the ResetPassBean rather than subclassing it. If you're not familiar with the Decorator pattern, this is a very straight-forward intro: http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/the-decorator-pattern-set-2-introduction-and-design/. When you're done, you only need one controller for both types of reset beans.

Comment: Thanks for a suggestion! Completely forgot about decorators, will try to use them here